# A question about functions and polynomials on rings

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with unity such that for every function $f : R \to R$ , $\exists \hat f (X) \in R[X]$ such that $f(r)=\hat f (r) , \forall r \in R$ ; how to show , without much manipulations ,  that $R$ is an integral domain ? Can the idea of associated primes come to use ? ( I can show , by some messy manipulations , that $R$ is an integral domain ) . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a fninte commutative ring?

Comment: @Youngsu : a commutative ring which is finite

Comment: You mean of finte length?

Comment: @Youngsu : No . The ring is finite as a set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function sending zero to zero and everything else to one must be represented by a polynomial $a_0 + a_1X + \cdots + a_nX^n$.  We have $a_0 = 0$, and for every $0 \neq x \in R$, we have

$$1 = a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n = x(a_1 + \cdots + a_nx^{n-1})$$

so $R$ is a field.

Comment: You can also prove that it's a finite field. Indeed, otherwise it is infinite, and there are as many polynomial functions as there are polynomials, that is the cardinality of the field, whereas there are $|K^K| = |2^K| > |K|$  functions $K\to K$ (where $K$ is our field and $|X| $ is the cardinality of $X$)

Comment: I'm just wondering whether the unitality of $R$ can be omitted.  That is, if $R$ is a commutative ring (not necessarily with unity) such that every $f:R\to R$ is a polynomial function, then is it true that $R$ is a finite field?

Comment: @Batominovski : yes that can be done ... I have a solution for that ...

Comment: @misao Would you mind posting the proof here?  (As an answer, not as part of your question.)